# how to create a list of c_ints and add element one at a time (python)

Tags: python, ctypes

Here is some code (from the docs):

```
IntArray5 = c_int * 5
ia = IntArray5(5, 1, 7, 33, 99)
```

How can I do something like:

```
N = 5
IntArrayN = c_int * N
ian = IntArrayN
ian.append(5)
ian.append(1)
ian.append(7)
ian.append(33)
ian.append(99)
```

So this raises an Attribute Error

Comment: use a `list` that has a variable length instead of `c_int` array that is - by definition - fixed length.

Comment: `c_int * N` uses the value of `N` at the time of execution which is `5`, it does not make the type have variable length.

Comment: variable in the sense that N is unknown before runtime

Comment: yeah, I understood that was the intent, I just don't see why you are trying to use `c_int` array in the first place when you clearly need a container with variable length.  A list is definitely the right way to go here.

Comment: Sorry I dont need a list. A list can not be sent to a c program expecting a void ptr

Comment: Avoid `ctypes` at all costs. Prefer `cffi` at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  is the way I was able to do it.

```
arr=[]
arr.append(5)
arr.append(1)
arr.append(7)
arr.append(33)
arr.append(99)

ian=(c_int*len(arr)(*arr)
print type(arr) # list
print type(ian) #__main.c_int_Array_N
```

output

```
<type 'list'>
<class '__main__.c_int_Array_4'>
```